# #sets.contains from thymeleaf always returning false

Tags: spring, set, thymeleaf, contains

In my current spring project, I am trying display a list of checkboxes which could be checked depending of a value from the server. This is the html code:

```
      <tr th:each="credencial : ${credenciais}">
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" th:id="${credencial.id}" th:checked="${#sets.contains(command.credenciais, credencial)}? 'checked': ''" th:attr="data-usuario=${command.id},data-url=@{/usuario/toggle_credencial}" onchange="toggle_credencial(this)"/>
        </td>

        <td>
          <span th:text="${credencial.nome}"></span>
        </td>

        <td>
          <ul>
            <li th:each="autorizacao : ${credencial.autorizacoes}" th:text="${autorizacao.nome}"></li>
          </ul>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

But when I run the application and open this page, no checkbox is checked because `#sets.contains` always return false.

The class being compared here is:

```
@Entity
public class Credencial extends Model {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String nome;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
  private List<Autorizacao> autorizacoes;

...

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return nome;
  }
}
```

I implement the method `equals` in the superclass `Model`:

```
public abstract class Model extends Object {
  public abstract Object getId();

  public boolean equals(Model object) {
    return toString().equals(object.toString());
  }

  public abstract String toString();
}
```

Anyone knows what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The [`th:checked` attribute in Thymeleaf expects a true/false value](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes), not a string. Does it worth with this?

```
th:checked="${#sets.contains(command.credenciais, credencial)}"
```

Comment: No, still do not work this way. I don't think `th:checked` works only with a true/false value. I have this: `th:checked="${command.enabled}? 'checked' : ''"` in another view which works fine. And `#set.contains` in `"${#sets.contains(command.credenciais, credencial)}? 'checked': ''"` returns a true/false value, right?

Comment: I linked to the documentation -- https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#fixed-value-boolean-attributes -- which says specifically that they are.  You are returning a string `'checked'` or a string `''` (rather than true or false).  If that doesn't change it, then it's likely in some other code you haven't posted.